# Flink Streaming - Save/Print dropped messages

Tags: java, apache-flink

I am new to Flink and streaming as well. I am using sliding window of size 5Sec with 1Sec slide to count number of messages (check code below) but I need help in saving(or print) dropped messages that arrived late, I've tried to use sideOutputLateData but it doesn't work for me

```
val sensorData = stream
    .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new SensorTimeAssigner)
    .map(x => (x.event_id, x.user_id, 1))
    .keyBy(x => (x._1, x._2))
    .timeWindow(Time.seconds(5), Time.seconds(1))
    .sum("_3")
```

with sideOutputLateData:

```
val lateOutputTag = OutputTag[(Int, Int, Int)]("late")
val sensorData = stream
    .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new SensorTimeAssigner)
    .map(x => (x.event_id, x.user_id, 1))
    .keyBy(x => (x._1, x._2))
    .timeWindow(Time.seconds(5), Time.seconds(1))
    .sideOutputLateData(lateOutputTag)
    .sum("_3")

sensorData
    .getSideOutput(lateOutputTag)
    .print()
```

Comment: Your code looks like it ought to work. How do you know there are late events?

Comment: @DavidAnderson, yes it does work but for late messages I would like to sink it into s3 so far I am not able to do it

Comment: For sinking to S3, I suggest you look at the StreamingFileSink. Be sure to enable checkpointing if you use it -- this is required, but not well documented.

Comment: Also, please update your question to reflect the actual situation.

Comment: @DavidAnderson thanks for the reply , my original issue is how I can print messages that getting dropped due to late arrival, the getSideOutput is not outputting any data

Answer (score 0):

One likely answer is that there aren't actually any late events. That will be the case if you haven't set the time characteristic to event time. It's not enough to use `assignTimestampsAndWatermarks`, you also need to either use

```
.window(SlidingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(5), Time.seconds(1)))
```

to force Flink to use event time windowing, or establish that event time windows are the default via

```
env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime)
```

Otherwise `timeWindow` is actually constructing a `SlidingProcessingTimeWindow`, in which case nothing can be late.

Another possibility is that your watermarking isn't behaving as you expect, and is allowing all of the events be on time.

Comment: I am already forcing Flink to use event time window by env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime), I did fix the issue by using ProcessWindowFunction (looks like that I have to use Process function with Flink 1.6 in order to get sideOutputLateData to work